# Photoshop: "Save for Web -> Done -> Save" results in different file size than "Save for Web -> Save..."

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, file-size

I have a large number of PNG images that are organized in some specific directories and subdirectories, like this:

- 0

  - 0

    - 0.png
- 1

  - 0

    - 0.png
    - 1.png
  - 1

    - 0.png
    - 1.png

, etc.

The problem is, their filesize is too big. In order to reduce it, I've tried to create an Action for optimizing and saving the whole batch via **Save for Web** option.

First, I open the image which initial filesize is 256KB. Then I adjust the **Save for Web** window parameters, and the filesize it is indicating is 27.55KB.

From here, I've tried two different approaches:

---

1) Clicking *Save...* from the "Save for Web" window.

The final filesize here is 27.55KB, as promised, but the problem here is that saves the image to the directory I manually choose, there is no way to just overwrite the image. So when creating a batch action it outputs the images to the same directory and thus **wrecks the whole folder organization**.

---

2) Clicking *Done* in the "Save for Web" window, so it closes with the settings supposedly applied to the image.

Then I save the image the normal way (Ctrl +S), so it just overwrites the original image, and thus the file organization is kept the same, which is good.

The problem here is that the **final filesize is 173KB instead of the "promised" 27.55KB.** So I suppose that it's not the same clicking "Done" and then saving than directly saving from the "Save for Web" window.

---

How could I solve this?
I am using Photoshop CS6

Comment: Hi Etherlind, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: "...so it closes with the settings supposedly applied to the image" Sounds implausible to me. This merely closes the dialog window and does not affect how Ctrl+S works.

Comment: @Kromster you're right. I tried opening my image and just saving it with overwrite, and the result is the same.The tooltip for the button "Done" is "Remember current settings and close dialog", though =/.

Comment: Tooltip probably refers to JUST THIS dialog, and does not affect anything outside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misunderstanding how the Save for Web tool works.

Save for Web *never* affects your actual document or any output other than when you click the <kbd>Save</kbd> button from the Save for Web window. The <kbd>Done</kbd> button only saves the settings you apply so that you can come back to the Save for Web window and save from there. It doesn't affect a normal save.

As for a solution, I'm not sure it's possible to automate a Save for Web whilst overwriting or keeping your folder structure. You could probably write a script to do the Save for Web for you. Or use something other than Photoshop (such as [ImageOptim](https://imageoptim.com/mac)).

There is a Photoshop extension here that looks like it may do what you need:

- http://blog.e-zest.net/photoshop-cs6-save-for-web-images-batch-processing-keeping-nested-folder-structure-intact/

There are a few links to possible solutions here too:

- https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1105633

Comment: Thanks! The "Image Processor Pro" plugin mentioned in both links is what I looked for.